# TypeError: Cannot read property '__esModule' of undefined when /* webpackPrefetch: true */ when SSR with loadable-component and serverless

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering, loadable-component

I am using serverless to deploy a React app with SSR. When I use loadable-compoennts for code splitting everything is fine until I try to prefretch resources. Adding /* webpackPrefetch: true */ to any loadable method causes a server side crash on importing my < App >

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '__esModule' of undefined
    at /Users/alexgawley/code/serverless/tmp/loadable-repro/.webpack/service/src/servers/static.js:29310:34
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/alexgawley/code/serverless/tmp/loadable-repro/.webpack/service/src/servers/static.js:29312:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at /Users/alexgawley/code/serverless/tmp/loadable-repro/node_modules/serverless-offline/dist/lambda/handler-runner/in-process-runner/InProcessRunner.js:157:133
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async InProcessRunner.run (/Users/alexgawley/code/serverless/tmp/loadable-repro/node_modules/serverless-offline/dist/lambda/handler-runner/in-process-runner/InProcessRunner.js:157:9)
To Reproduce
```

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

```
git clone https://github.com/agawley/loadable-repro
npm i
npm run offline
```

load http://localhost:3000

The page should load with a 'show/hide' link which reveals the lazy-loaded component SomeText. If you remove the /* webpackPrefetch: true */ comment from app.js you get the expected behaviour (but no prefetching!)

```
## System:
 - OS: macOS 10.15.7
 - CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8850H CPU @ 2.60GHz
 - Memory: 834.46 MB / 16.00 GB
 - Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh
## Binaries:
 - Node: 12.22.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.1/bin/node
 - Yarn: 1.22.10 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
 - npm: 7.13.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.1/bin/npm
## npmPackages:
 - @loadable/babel-plugin: ^5.13.2 => 5.13.2 
 - @loadable/component: ^5.15.0 => 5.15.0 
 - @loadable/server: ^5.15.0 => 5.15.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Got an answer from webpack. It's a [bug in webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/12993). [PR to fix](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/13431) (not yet accepted, but works as patch)